# How to Sync Thunderbird Contacts with Gmail Contacts

Tags: sync, thunderbird

I have thunderbird 3.0 with the Zindus plugin. However it seems that Zindus syncs one way.

For example I type a new email address into thunderbird and then go to my gmail account and it has no record of this contact.

So is there a plugin or some setting that will make Zindus work both ways?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'd recommend the [Google Contacts add-on for Thunderbird](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/7307) (update 2015: this is no longer supported or available for recent versions of Thunderbird >24.X)

[image]

> **Access bi-directionaly to Google
>   contacts** via address books. This
>   extension detects gmail accounts which
>   have already set up and creates
>   address books for each of them. Cards
>   in the address books are synchronized
>   with Google contacts; they represent
>   the current Google contacts contents
>   and Google contacts will be modified
>   when you modify the cards. TB's
>   mailing lists and Google's contacts
>   groups are synchronized in the same
>   manner.

For more information, [click this link.](http://outgoing.mozilla.org/v1/886311bbe8084acb8b282768625bd1757db72991/http%3A//hogiblog.blogspot.com/2008/05/synchronizing-google-contacts-and.html)

Comment: This add-on would almost make me drop Outlook :-O

Comment: Why the heck didn't this pop out when I was searching couple months ago :-s

Awesome stuff.

Comment: Well I was suprised as well! There is absolutely nothing like this for Outlook

Comment: How do I get this bi-directionaly to work? It seems like the test contact I wrote in thunderbird does not show up in gmail.

Comment: Hmm I tried adding my contact to the personal address book and the one labeled with my Gmail account yet both of the tests I did do not sync.

Answer (score 5):

I've tried a few (including Zindus), and have settled on gContactSync:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/8451

Can't say how it compares to Google Contacts in particular, but I'm using gContactSync on three PCs, and syncing my Google contacts with my iPhone, and am *very* happy.

Comment: gContactSync seems to work as I want it too. However do you know how I can have all the new contacts I write go into the gmail account one? Like I have multiple accounts(some for my websites) and I would love if they got put it my gmail account even if I am not writing the message from the gmail account.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do... I can't find any per-account address book setting.  Do you mean when you send email, the address book that the recipient automatically gets added to?  There's only one setting for that, for all accounts: it's in Tools/Options, in the Composition section, in the Addressing tab, where it says "Automatically add outgoing email addresses to my" - choose the address book that synchronizes with gContactSync.

Comment: I don't know where it came from then but when I go to my thunderbird's address book I have an address book called "Personal Address Book" I did not make this.

Comment: That's the default address book that is set up when Thunderbird is set up.  You can just ignore it, and put your addresses in whatever address book you set up to sync with gContactSync.  If you right-click on a received address and select Add to Address Book, it adds it to the address book in the "Automatically add outgoing email addresses to my" setting (even if that option is not checked).

Comment: As of 5/29/15, [Google contacts](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/google-contacts/?src=ss) won't sync properly, and you just keep getting password prompts (perhaps because of Google API change?). [gContactSync](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/gcontactsync/) is working, so I would recommend that.

Comment: But not for contact photos :(

Answer (score 1):

**Getting powerful live integration is actually quite easy now.** 
Go to 'Settings/Composition & Addressing' for one of the email accounts.
Under 'Addressing' select 'Use a different LDAP server:' 
Select 'Edit Directories'.
In the pop-up enter:
Name: GoogleLDAP
Hostname: ldap.gmail.com
Port number: 389
Click 'Ok'. 
Back under 'Addressing/ Use a different LDAP server:' for this and any other accounts select 'GoogleLDAP'.
That is it! You are now fully synchronized!

Comment: +1 for the idea and the 2013 update. But it does not work in my case: I use Thunderbird v17, I use secure GMail login, I use an alias e-mail address... As I prefer using LDAP than installing an extension => I will try again this idea later. Please give more information: tested version, OS... How does Thunderbird know the LDAP password? Please give some useful links about this purpose. Cheers

Comment: This does not seem to work, get a "Replication failed" error when trying to download it.

Comment: This does not seem to work for me.  I get an error: "LDAP Server Search Problem.  Error code 0x80070057: Unknown error.  Please contact your System Administrator."

Comment: Just tried this in TB 52.0. Followed the steps but it didn't add any contacts to the the GoogleLDAP address book even after waiting 10 minutes. I also tried the Reset from Server function but that made no difference. Does the above method need changing?