# Sync contacts with groups, and multiple e-mails between Thunderbird and Gmail (or alternative e-mail client?)

Tags: sync, thunderbird, google-contacts

I am planning to migrate my contacts list into Thunderbird, plus I've read many posts on how to sync the Address Book in Mozilla Thunderbird with contacts in Gmail, such as:

[How to Sync Thunderbird Contacts with Gmail Contacts](https://superuser.com/questions/111882/how-to-sync-thunderbird-contacts-with-gmail-contacts)

However, three problems remain:

1) Many of my contacts have multiple e-mails, and it seems they would be lost because Thunderbird's address book only supports two e-mails.

2) I like to organise my contacts into groups/lists, but Gmail contacts does not seem to support SYNCING this information?

3) Gmail consolidates first and last names into one field, I like to keep them separate.

Is is possible to solve the three issues when syncing between Thunderbird and Gmail? (I checked out Plaxo, but I heard it is unstable? Can anyone confirm?)

If not, are there suitable replacements for Thunderbird as an offline client, and Gmail as web access to contacts? Again I would like them to stay in sync.

Sorry for the long post, but thanks for your insights!

Comment: Sorry I can't help, but I am interested in your objective for this migration. Just for offline access to contacts? I have just about finished migrating contacts from a range or sources to Gmail! Perhaps also specify the OS you're wanting to use?

Comment: I want to be able to do this under Linux and Mac OS X. I would like my offline contacts and GMail contacts to be in sync and accessible.

Answer (score 1):

1) I have used MS Outlook (I know, boo hiss) and it will support up to 3 email addresses and syncs well using the Google Apps sync tool

2) While you can create new contact groups in GMail, I have yet to find a way to automatically migrate them. If anyone figures this out it would make my life easier.

3) Though Gmail only contains a single field for usertname, the synced contact appears to maintain integrity in MS Outlook and remains searchable by first or last name.

Hope this helps some.