# How can I import Gmail contacts into Thunderbird?

Tags: linux, gmail, fedora

```
$ rpm -qa | grep -i "^thunderbird"
thunderbird-enigmail-1.1.2-1.fc14.i686
thunderbird-3.1.7-2.fc14.i686
$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version: :core-4.0-ia32:core-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: Fedora
Description: Fedora release 14 (Laughlin)
Release: 14
Codename: Laughlin
$
```

I exported all my contacts from Gmail in Outlook csv format. Then I opened the "Address book" in Thunderbird, and imported them:

[image]

What am I missing? Is there no way* to import contacts from Gmail to Thunderbird with mouse clicking only?

Do I have to write a script that modifies the .csv file, so that it could be imported in Thunderbird?

Comment: I suggest you either make this clearly a programming question (e.g. show us the csv format from Gmail and the one Thunderbird exports) or ask this on SuperUser: http://superuser.com/

Comment: Can you show us the format of the csv file?  Take a screenshot of it in Open Office or something please.

Comment: May be this addon will help [link](http://superuser.com/questions/111882/how-to-sync-thunderbird-contacts-with-gmail-contacts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than doing a one time load of the contacts like that it may be better, unless you're going to stop using gmail completely, to use the [Zindus extension to Thunderbird](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/zindus/) to keep the two synchronised automatically.